# Mysql select from one table but comparing with ids from 2 tables and a parameter

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

just got stuck with a mysql statment.

The scenario is i have a userId (1 in this case) and i want to select the friends (from the user table) using the friends table.
Was trying with this statment below but was not able to make it work.

```
Select User.* From User 
Inner join Friends f on Friends.userId = 1
inner join User u on User.idUser = Friends.friendId;
```

tabels

```
CREATE TABLE `Friends` (
  `idFriends` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friendId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFriends`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idFriends_UNIQUE` (`idFriends`),
  KEY `fk_Friends_User_idx` (`userId`),

CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `idUser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUser')
```

Would be so grateful for help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the idUser value in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  fu.*
FROM    User u 
        INNER JOIN Friends f on u.idUser = f.friendId
        INNER JOIN User fu on f.userId = fu.idUser
WHERE   u.idUser = 1;
```